React Native Webview performance impacts entire app
I have a React Native application that uses a 3D engine (BabylonJS) inside react-native-webview.
When the WebView FPS drops (let's say from 60fps to 30fps), the React Native UI FPS (as seen in the RN performance profiler) of the RN application drops to 30 as well. I would have expected that if the WebView performance drops, it's contained to within the WebView.
As an example, I can use split screen with another application and it's performance is not impacted, so the tablet itself is necessarily running slow.
Is there a way to avoid this so that any performance issues inside the WebView don't impact the rest of the app so that if the Webview is running at 30fps, the main app still runs at 60fps?
Thanks!
Casey.

This was originally asked on https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/discussions/3596
